# Linkedin : oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null

Tags: android, exception, null, linkedin-api, provider

I am going to access linkedin profile in my android app. I used the below code which is working fine on android devices, but getting crashed on emulator. Does't know where is the problem. My code is below.

Config.java

```
public class Config {

    public static String LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY = "75rbbjsc94argh";
    public static String LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET = "G85WTKgcIijk4U6Yu";
    public static String scopeParams = "rw_nus+r_basicprofile+r_fullprofile+r_emailaddress+r_network+r_contactinfo+rw_groups+rw_company_admin";

    public static String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
    public static String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "callback";
    //public static String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
    public static String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-linkedin://callback";
}
```

LinkedInSampleActivity.java

```
public class LinkedInSampleActivity extends Activity {
    Button login;
    Button share;
    EditText et;
    TextView name;
    ImageView photo;
    public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";

    final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
            .getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(
                    Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET, Config.scopeParams);
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                    Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
    LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
    LinkedInApiClient client;
    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_share);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                linkedInLogin();
            }
        });
    }

    private void linkedInLogin() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                LinkedInSampleActivity.this);

        LinkedinDialog d = new LinkedinDialog(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                progressDialog);
        d.show();

        // set call back listener to get oauth_verifier value
        d.setVerifierListener(new OnVerifyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVerify(String verifier) {
                try {
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "verifier: " + verifier);

                    accessToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService
                            .getOAuthAccessToken(LinkedinDialog.liToken,
                                    verifier);
                    LinkedinDialog.factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);


                    client.postNetworkUpdate("Testing by Umesh!!! LinkedIn wall post from Android app");


                    Person p2 = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID)); 
                    Person p = client.getProfileById(p2.getId(), EnumSet.of(
                    ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                    ProfileField.LAST_NAME,
                    ProfileField.SKILLS,
                    ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                    ProfileField.SUMMARY,
                    ProfileField.LANGUAGES,
                    ProfileField.LANGUAGES_LANGUAGE_NAME,
                    ProfileField.LANGUAGES_PROFICIENCY_NAME,
                    ProfileField.LANGUAGES_LANGUAGE,
                    ProfileField.HONORS,
                    ProfileField.INTERESTS,
                    ProfileField.POSITIONS,
                    ProfileField.EDUCATIONS,
                    ProfileField.INDUSTRY,
                    ProfileField.API_STANDARD_PROFILE_REQUEST,
                    ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
                    ProfileField.PUBLIC_PROFILE_URL));

                    name.setText("Welcome " + p.getFirstName() + " "+ p.getLastName());

                    Log.i("LinkedinSample","ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getToken());
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample","ln_access_token: " + accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    Log.i("FirstName"," : " + p.getFirstName());
                    Log.i("LastName"," : " + p.getLastName());
                    Log.i("User Summary"," : " + p.getSummary());
                    Log.i("Headline"," : " + p.getHeadline());
                    Log.i("Interest"," : "+p.getInterests());

                    //----------------------------------------------------

                    for (Position position:p.getPositions().getPositionList())
                    {
                        Log.i("position "," : " + position.getTitle());
                        Log.i("comp "," : " + position.getCompany().getName());

                    }

                    for (Education education:p.getEducations().getEducationList()) 
                    {
                        Log.i("Degree "," : "+ education.getDegree());
                        Log.i("School name "," : "+ education.getSchoolName());

                    }
                    Log.i("Language "," : ");
                    for(Language language:p.getLanguages().getLanguageList())
                    {
                        Log.i(""," : "+language.getLanguage().getName());
                    }
                    Log.i("Skill "," : ");
                    for(Skill skill:p.getSkills().getSkillList())
                    {
                        Log.i(""," : "+skill.getSkill().getName());
                    }
                    Log.i("Honor"," : "+p.getHonors());
                    //----------------------------------------------------

                    name.setVisibility(0);
                    login.setVisibility(4);
                    share.setVisibility(0);
                    et.setVisibility(0);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("LinkedinSample", "error to get verifier");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        // set progress dialog
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

LinkedinDialog.java

```
public class LinkedinDialog extends Dialog {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    public static LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
    public static LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
    public static LinkedInRequestToken liToken;

    //Construct a new LinkedIn dialog

    public LinkedinDialog(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
        super(context);
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// must call before super.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ln_dialog);
        setWebView();
    }

    // set webview.
    private void setWebView() {
        LinkedinDialog.oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance()
                .createLinkedInOAuthService(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY,
                        Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        LinkedinDialog.factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(
                Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);

        LinkedinDialog.liToken = LinkedinDialog.oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkitWebView1);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Log.i("LinkedinSample", LinkedinDialog.liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        mWebView.loadUrl(LinkedinDialog.liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        mWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
                if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    //webview client for internal url loading

    class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(Config.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
                cancel();
                for (OnVerifyListener d : listeners) {
                    // call listener method
                    d.onVerify(verifier);
                }
            } else if (url.contains("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/redorangetechnologies.com")) {
                cancel();
            } else {
                Log.i("LinkedinSample", "url: " + url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * List of listener.
     */
    private List<OnVerifyListener> listeners = new ArrayList<OnVerifyListener>();

    /**
     * Register a callback to be invoked when authentication have finished.
     * 
     * @param data
     *            The callback that will run
     */
    public void setVerifierListener(OnVerifyListener data) {
        listeners.add(data);
    }

    /**
     * Listener for oauth_verifier.
     */
    interface OnVerifyListener {
        /**
         * invoked when authentication have finished.
         * 
         * @param verifier
         *            oauth_verifier code.
         */
        public void onVerify(String verifier);
    }
}
```

App crashed, on clicking login button, Error shows on setWebView(); in LinkedinDialog class.

Following is the logcat :

```
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544): com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:205)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.mukesh.linkedin.LinkedinDialog.setWebView(LinkedinDialog.java:65)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.mukesh.linkedin.LinkedinDialog.onCreate(LinkedinDialog.java:54)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:340)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:253)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.mukesh.linkedin.LinkedInSampleActivity.linkedInLogin(LinkedInSampleActivity.java:100)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.mukesh.linkedin.LinkedInSampleActivity.access$0(LinkedInSampleActivity.java:94)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.mukesh.linkedin.LinkedInSampleActivity$1.onClick(LinkedInSampleActivity.java:69)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:196)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     ... 18 more
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:460)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:432)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:164)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider.sendRequest(DefaultOAuthProvider.java:48)
01-17 15:50:06.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2544):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:177)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the below function after setContentView() in onCreate().

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

This worked for me. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hi Pavan, Your answer is accepted. Thank you. But there is one more thing that app will be forced closed, when you call for login authentication. This is because, if our device time does not match with the current server time. I solved this issue. I cought this exception and turn the user towards device time Setting.

Comment: hii umesh can u tell me how you solved this problem. i am getting same issue.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error out of sudden. I tried this but not working for me. Do you have any other solution for this problem. It would be helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By the way

It's better to use AsyncTask for background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the strict mode policy set your mobile date and time correctly it will work fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11112286)

Comment: i was facing the same issue but using strict mode policy and setting date it worked for me. if u don't believe just change the date and try to login it will crash in all Asus devices.