# Accessing Linkedin API in Android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am working on a small android application. I have to access LinkedIn through it's API call. For this I am using linkedin-j-android.jar. But after clicking on a button to get the linkedin login screen, I am getting the error below:

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken .
```

For this I have created one application using linkedIn I got the consumer and secret key.but even though I am facing this issue.can any one share your thoughts to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21673071/2091181

Comment: I would suggest using the official linked in sdk. https://developer.linkedin.com/

Comment: Why don't you use Android SDK or Rest API on official LinkedIn developers page, its quite user friendly